# How to manage database settings in Yii while running?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I want to let user manage database connection settings from website itself. I've thought that I would save db setting in a txt file and before every connection these would be read from this file first. Is it even possible?

I tried to use this in the main config file, but it does not work:

```
  $myfile = Yii::app()->file->set('assets/settings.txt', true);
  $array = explode("\r\n", $myfile->getContents());
  $dblink = $array[0];
  ...
  'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => $dblink,
  ...
```

Comment: What is in settings.txt? Also for security make sure settings.txt can not be access from the outside otherwise this is a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: are you using multiple db's?